# Angular 2 with webpack gets Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: testing, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, referenceerror

I have a working Angular 2 project that I tryed to add some tests to. Now with the tests I added webpack and now have some problem I am not able to solve with the online researche. Here is the errormessage I get in the browser:
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined at localhost/:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined at systemjs.config.js:42 

Here my structur:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ktY2.jpg
Here my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PQM Monitor</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/styles.css">
    <script>
        System.import('/src/app').catch(function(err){console.error(err);});
    </script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/images/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image"/>
    <base href="/src">
</head>
<body>
<info>Loading...</info>
<script src="src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                          'dist', //'src/app',
        '@angular':                     'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api':   'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                         'node_modules/rxjs',
        'polyfill':                     'node_modules/babel-polyfill',
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                          { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                         { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api':   { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling System before importing it, simple change your system import position to be sure it's called after the import of `system.src.js` file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PQM Monitor</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/styles.css">
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/images/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image"/>
    <base href="/src">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    System.import('/src/app').catch(function(err){console.error(err);});
</script>
<info>Loading...</info>
<script src="src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I should have seen that myself, but there is still the error with "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined" from the systemjs.config.js file. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Oh yes sure, let me move the system config file import after the system file on the html  example

Comment: That solved my asked problem, thanks again. But now I get a "Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <(…)" any idea how to fix that?

Comment: change your loading from /src/app for /app, system doesn't know what is /src/app but it knows what is /app since you specified it in the map

Comment: the second fix worked perfectly. Now after some more work I got a new bug that I dont know what to do with. If you have time look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041459/angular-2-with-webpack-gets-error-systemjs-process-is-not-defined